# How to show Genres, Artists and Albums as lists by popularity with the Spotify iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, swift, spotify

I am working on an app that i believe would enhance music streaming apps and since Spotify provide an iOS SDK, i thought this would be a great place to start. What I am trying to do is create a tabBarController with each tab going to a separate view. These views would display the most popular Artists, Genres and Albums for the user's locality. How would i go about populating the views? I understand how iOS development works and I can work well with UITableViews, so i would just need pointing in the right direction in terms of using Spotify with it. I've read through the Spotify iOS SDK but very little makes sense and there are not many other resources either, especially in Swift.